# How to compare char and char * in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, comparison, c-strings

I'm not sure why this isn't working, it doesn't print anything. csvArry has 3 elements in it and capList has 4 elements. I want to search capList to see if there is an element in it that matches an element in csvArray.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    char *csvArray[] = {"1000", "CAP_SYS_ADMIN", "CAP_SYS_RAW"};
    char *capList[] = {"CAP_SYS_SETFCAP", "CAP_SYS_SETPCAP", "CAP_SYS_ADMIN", "CAP_SYS_RAW"};

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    while(i<3){
          for(j=0;j<4;j++){
              if(strcmp(csvArray[i],capList[j]) == 0){
                        printf("Match");
              }
          }
          i++;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` is returning `0` if equal.

Comment: So I added == 0 in the if statement and it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/2Wurgq)

Comment: It does for me https://ideone.com/YZNEU7

Comment: `stdout` is line-buffered.  you never send a newline character `\n` to flush the buffer or `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons true, but `stdout` should be automatically flushed when the program exits.

Comment: @Kevin I don't believe there is any requirement to do so.  Some systems may, others may not.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function *the return from the initial call to main ...  flushes and closes all streams ...*

Comment: @Kevin I'm having difficulty finding that in the actual C standard.  That page cites the C11 standard 5.1.2.2.1 (5.1.2.2.3 is the part, however, about program termination that we're interested in).  Where it describes termination behavior, it says nothing about flushing buffers.  I don't know where they got that part in parentheses, but I cannot find it in the cited section of the C11 standard working draft.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm not skilled at searching the standard, but [5.1.2.2.3](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.3.html) says returning from main is equivalent to calling `exit`. I can't find a description of `exit` in the standard, but all the man pages I've looked through say that it flushes and closes all open streams.

Comment: @Kevin Good call.  7.22.4.4 describes the behavior of `exit()`.  Paragraph 4: *Next,  all  open  streams  with  unwritten  buffered  data  are  flushed,  all  open  streams  are closed, and all files created by the tmpfile function are removed.*

Comment: Your code prints "MatchMatch" as I'd expect it would. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *csvArray[] = {"1000", "CAP_SYS_ADMIN", "CAP_SYS_RAW"};
    char *capList[] = {"CAP_SYS_SETFCAP", "CAP_SYS_SETPCAP", "CAP_SYS_ADMIN", "CAP_SYS_RAW"};

    int size = sizeof(csvArray) / sizeof(csvArray[0]);
    int sizeOfList = sizeof(capList) / sizeof(capList[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfList; j++) {
            if (strcmp(csvArray[i], capList[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s Match\n", csvArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program tries to find which elements are common to both and it prints which are common too.

> **Output**

```
CAP_SYS_ADMIN Match
CAP_SYS_RAW Match
```

Comment: Strings should not be compared with `==`.  There's no guarantee that two strings literals point to the same place.